# how to parse json to array list in windows store app c#

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

i am trying to parse json to array in windows store app using c#.

my json is as follows

```
{
"catlist": [
    {
        "area_id": "1",
        "area_name": "Ko",
        "categories": [
            {
                "cat_id": "1",
                "cat_name": "Hot",
                "chk_value": "2",
                "sublist": [
                    {
                        "sub_id": "5",
                        "sub_name": "Beach"
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_id": "6",
                        "sub_name": "Beach"
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_id": "7",
                        "sub_name": "Beach"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "cat_id": "2",
                "cat_name": "Dining",
                "chk_value": "1",
                "sublist": [
                    {
                        "sub_id": "1",
                        "sub_name": "Road"
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_id": "2",
                        "sub_name": "Soi "
                    }
                ]
            }]}
```

what is the easiest way to parse it into an array of json elements and use it for data binding

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json)

`var array = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(jsonString);`

Using WinRT API's [`JsonArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.jsonarray%28v=win.10%29.aspx) class

`var array = Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray.Parse(jsonString);`

BTW, your JSON is invalid according to [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com)

---

According to me this is valid JSON array

```
[
    {
        "catlist": [
            {
                "area_id": "1",
                "area_name": "Ko",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "cat_id": "1",
                        "cat_name": "Hot",
                        "chk_value": "2",
                        "sublist": [
                            {
                                "sub_id": "5",
                                "sub_name": "Beach"
                            },
                            {
                                "sub_id": "6",
                                "sub_name": "Beach"
                            },
                            {
                                "sub_id": "7",
                                "sub_name": "Beach"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "cat_id": "2",
                        "cat_name": "Dining",
                        "chk_value": "1",
                        "sublist": [
                            {
                                "sub_id": "1",
                                "sub_name": "Road"
                            },
                            {
                                "sub_id": "2",
                                "sub_name": "Soi "
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If you want to deserialize the JSON, you should like this.

```
var Obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(jsonString);

public class Sublist
{
    public string sub_id { get; set; }
    public string sub_name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string cat_id { get; set; }
    public string cat_name { get; set; }
    public string chk_value { get; set; }
    public List<Sublist> sublist { get; set; }
}

public class Catlist
{
    public string area_id { get; set; }
    public string area_name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Catlist> catlist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i got error response                                               Invalid character at position 0.
   at Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray.Parse(String input)is it because of the initial key

Comment: As I said it's not valid JSON, that's why you are getting error. I am posting valid JSON, I am not sure if it's correct according to your requirement.

Comment: @suvishvalsan The error is because that is a JSON object, not a JSON array. You can use `JsonObject.Parse()` for objects, or if it is a random JSON string and you don't know if it is an object, an array or something else, use `JsonValue.Parse()`.

Comment: can you suggest a way to sterilize the json